# rstrip(), lstrip(), and strip() in Python

Tags: python, strip

I am using Sublime Text version 3.0 and my input is:

```
little_known_person = "' Christopher '"

print(little_known_person.strip())
```

but my output is `' Christopher '` instead of `'Christopher'`. The output is the same if I try the `rstrip()` and `lstrip()` methods.

Comment: Stripping removes outmost white space. Your whitespace is inside quotes in the string so it won’t be removed.

Comment: `print(little_known_person.strip("' "))`

Answer (score 2):

You need to strip leading/trailing whitespace *and* single quotes. The default, with no argument, is to strip only whitespace.

```
little_known_person.strip(" '")
```

The argument is an arbitrary iterable (`str`, `list`, `tuple`, etc) containing characters that should be stripped. The order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip whitepaces and single quotes and then re-add the quotes:

```
little_known_person = "'" + little_known_person.strip(" '") + "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try if the following approach solves your issue:

```py
>>> little_known_person = "' Christopher '"
>>> little_known_person.replace("'", "").strip()
'Christopher'
```